# ImageView adjustViewBounds not working with fitXY

Tags: android, button, imageview, scaletype, adjustviewbounds

I use the following code to show my button

(Because I need to add the text on the button, so I will not use the ImageButton)

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bottom001"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But the ImageView will have some empty area in the View

I think "fitXY" will fill the View, but it didn't

[image: bottom]

How can I do in this case?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: it's because you are make the image to fit the whole imageview then how will the adjust bound work..buddy

Comment: Thanks , but I need the button to fill the width.....and the height scale with the ratio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` And Use `LinearLayout`

Finally

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/test"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

For details please read  [android-imageview-scaletype-samples](http://etcodehome.blogspot.in/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html)

### **[FIT_XY](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)**

Scale the image using FILL.Stretch the picture inside the available width and height, disgarding the aspect ratio.

Comment: But I need the ImageView to fill the width , how should I do?

Comment: then use android:scaleType="fitCenter" and android:layout_width='fill_parent'

Comment: @陳家錡 Response please, Working or not?

Comment: wait ,in here i testing

Comment: God , I'm sorry , I think it's my pic's problem

Comment: I'm really sorry for you , the empty area is for shadow

Comment: Because the picture got from the UI desginer

Comment: @陳家錡 Your xml works smoothly . yes,please change your image

Comment: does `scaleType = FitXY` override `adjustViewBounds = true`